# Is it possible to set unique Intent filter?

Tags: android, android-intent

What I am trying to achieve is to open Activity automatically when URL is clicked on a browser, notes app or messenger.

So I have this URL format:
http://testsite.com/code/AB1234

In AndroidManifest.xml, I have set Intent filter for Activity:

```
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="testsite.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/code"
            android:scheme="http" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In HomeActivity, just getting code from URL and showing it on Toast:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    String code = getIntent().getData().getLastPathSegment();
    Toast.makeText(this, code, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

When I click on link, system is showing my application and browser application on application chooser. I know that this URL can be handled browser also. I would like to know how to make my intent filter to have priority if it is possible.

Is it possible to open my app automatically? If yes how to make it? How I should change my intent filter?

Comment: This link should help. It is possible to directly open app from a url for devices running Android 6.0 and above but below that user always gets a pop-up.
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

Comment: you can try to define your custom protocol, like `myapp://something` instead of `http://something`. This kind of URLs will not be handled by browser, and it will use your app by default. But be aware that clicking on such URL having no your app install will lead to something like *page not found* in the browser

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the link, the easiest way to achieve what you want is to set unique scheme for your app.

```
<data android:host="testsite.com"
      android:pathPrefix="/code"
      android:scheme="myapp" />
```